# How to change tap sound of an Android device?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, audio

The tap sound on my new Jelly Bean Android tablet sounds cheap and tinny. Is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**

You cannot *change* it unless you have root access. But you can disable it if you don't like it. Go to Settings => Sounds => Deselect the `Touch Sounds` option.

Just in case you have root access, go to `/System/media/audio/ui/` and replace the file named `touch.ogg` or `tick.ogg` or `effec_tick.ogg` or the one with a similar name.